# Использование схем данных для группировки сущностей

Tags: sql, sql-server

Хорошая ли практика использовать различные схемы в БД для группировки сущностный?
При это никакой спец. разрешения на схемы не будут использоваться.

Просто очень часто вижу картину похожую на следующую в dbo:

dbo.User

dbo.UserAccaunt

dbo.UserHistory

И будет ли правильно, все это вынести из dbo в схему user, откинув приставку User?

Comment: мельчить то уж особо смысла нет, но для этого схемы данных и предназначены.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Изначально все же схема была внедрена как дополнительный логический контекст безопасности внутри базы-данных. Но я часто видел практику выделения отдельных схем для удобства ориентирования в объектах БД, например для:

- Разделения по функциональным модулям приложения
- Привязки к разным приложениям объектов БД (актуально в Azure, где за каждую новую SQL БД приходится платить, а если объем данных небольшой - можно несколько приложений уместить в одной SQL БД и сэкономить денег)
- Версионирование объектов БД с помощью схем
- Разделение объектов БД по доменам предметной области (business domain) - как раз ваш случай

Собственно ответ на вопрос: это нормальная практика, которая помогает ориентироваться в структуре объектов БД разработчику, но не единственная. Применять или не применять больше зависит от существующих стандартов и договоренностей у вас в команде.